# How can I set this so I can't enter any more than four numbers for cin?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple user input. I tried to set it up so there would be four numbers entered by the user. It works for four inputs from user. It does not end after four separate numbers.  Also managed to find out that I can trigger an endless repeating loop if one really long number is entered.  Then I have to press cntrl+C to stop the code from running.  This is in Microsoft Visual Studio if that is important.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void GameBoy ()
{
    cout<< "\nYou think you are this badass hacker so...." <<endl;
    cout<< "Please enter the correct combination of numbers..." <<endl;

    int a {};
    int b {};
    int c {};
    int d {};
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

    double sum = a + b + c + d;
    int prod = a * b * c * d;
    double average = sum / 4;
    cout << average << endl;
    if (sum != average && average == sum)
    {
        cout << "You're a goober!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You're still an goober :-P" << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
   {
        GameBoy ();
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: read the numbers in a loop and add them to a vector. std::vector<int> values. then in loop int v; c >> v; values.push_back(v);

Comment: ok I will try that as well.  This is what I really like about stackoverflow.  Having different ways of doing stuff.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just FYI: `int a{}; int b{}; int c{}; int d{}` is overkill. Just type `int a, b, c, d` - you initialise these values in your `cin` on the next line anyway.

Comment: Also, `x != y && y == x` will always be `false` when `x`, `y` are `int`s; so your `GameBoy` function will always output `You're still an goober!!` regardless of input.

Comment: Wow hey thanks I will incorporate that as well.  I really appreciate all this input.  It's really humbling how helpful people really are here.  Should have started this stuff many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function to return bool (true if all numbers are in the correct range, false if some number is out of range). Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool GameBoy() {
  cout << "\nYou think you are this badass hacker so...." << endl;
  cout << "Please enter the correct combination of numbers..." << endl;

  int a{};
  int b{};
  int c{};
  int d{};
  cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

  double sum = a + b + c + d;
  int prod = a * b * c * d;
  double average = sum / 4;
  cout << average << endl;
  if (sum != average && average == sum) {
    cout << "You're a goober!!" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "You're still an goober :-P" << endl;
  }
  // if (Correct condition)
  // return true;
  // else Wrong condition
  // return false
}

int main() {
  while (GameBoy()) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel silly now.  Just finished posting this question and found out what I needed to stop that endless loop. Once I added this then the issue stopped.  Wow won't forget that!.

cin.clear();
cin.ignore();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).